# Predicate on a Map<String, String> field using spring-data-mongodb

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

As the subject says, I have problems with a query involving a `Predicate` on a `Map<String, String>` field.

I have the following test case that reproduces the problem:

```
  @Test
  public void testReferencesPredicate() throws Exception {

            //cleans the event collection
            final DBCollection event = mongoTemplate.getCollection("event");
            event.drop();

            final Event anEvent = new Event();
            //event has some more fields

            final Map<String, String> someRefs = new HashMap<>();
            someRefs.put("a", "b");
            anEvent.setReferences(someRefs);

            final Event save = this.eventRepository.save(anEvent);

            assertNotNull(save);

            final BooleanBuilder refPredicate = new BooleanBuilder();

            final Map<String, String> references = new HashMap<>();
            references.put("a", "b");

            for (final Map.Entry<String, String> stringObjectEntry : references.entrySet()) {

                final String key = stringObjectEntry.getKey();
                final String value = stringObjectEntry.getValue();

                // this also doesn't work: refPredicate.and(QEvent.event.references.contains(key, value));
                refPredicate.and(QEvent.event.references.get(key).eq(value));

            }

            final Pageable firstPage = new PageRequest(1, 1);
            final Page<Event> all = this.eventRepository.findAll(refPredicate, firstPage);
            assertNotNull(all);
            assertEquals(1, all.getContent().size());
//the eventRepository is like this: public interface EventRepository extends MongoRepository<Event, ObjectId>,
        QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Event>,

        }
```

When mongo is logging to stdout the queries the client is performing, I see the following:

```
2015-07-30T10:49:24.399+0200 I QUERY    [conn3] query some-db.event query: { references.a: "b" } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 nscannedObjects:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:1 reslen:207 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 1 } } } 0ms
```

It seems the query performed is different from the query that works from the mongo client:

```
e = db.getCollection("event")
e.find({ "references.a": "b" })
```

Please note the quotes around `references.a`, that I think are used to access a nested json document.

Has someone experienced this already?

I am on `spring-data-mongodb-1.7.0.RELEASE` on mongodb v3.0.4

Comment: What you see in the log is the output of the MongoDB Java driver's DBObject's `toString()` method. That – as I had to learn recently as well – is not expected (at least by driver devs) to necessarily be executable or even remotely equivalent with what the JavaScript console expects. Do you have a simple sample project to reproduce the error? If so I'd suggest to create a ticket in our JIRA.

Comment: @OliverGierke so the difference is not relevant according to you? this code is the most I can share by now to reproduce the problem, maybe later I can wrap it in a project, but there's not really much more than this.

Comment: My point here is to get something executable. Something I can `mvn clean test` (or equivalent) and see a test fail. It's hard to judge as unfortunately the output is not very helpful due to the reasons documented above.